# How to avoid asking the clients to clear browser cache for the latest Javascript changes?

Tags: javascript, iis, coldfusion, requirejs, http-caching

A client would report a bug in our JS-heavy app, we fixed it, but the client's browser still using the cached copy.  This happens a lot, and asking our clients to flush their browser cache seems very low-tech and troublesome.

We are aware of the `?ver=xxx` workaround, but we use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) so it's not easy to apply such hack.

Would HTTP cache control work?  However, we noticed IIS does not pick up the JS file changes right away and the HTTP header (last modified) does not reflect the latest changes.

Would ETag work better?  Is it better or worse then last modified on IIS?

Any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: So are you loading all your scripts with RequireJS?

Comment: Not all, but if the `?ver=` is still the best way, then we'll continue to use it.

Comment: Well the "best" way, to use caching properly, is to make the URL like: `/resources/cachebusterValueHere/js/script.js`, and you would update `cachebusterValueHere` when your project needs a new version. This would require you to change how your server maps this URL, and shouldn't be too hard. And you would have to set up your server to use the correct headers to make sure they're cached

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RequireJS has a [cache busting property](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-urlArgs) that you can use -:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
});
```

Edit -: However, as Ian pointed out below, in their documents it is recommended not to use it this way for production code.

Everytime you push a new commit to production maybe you can instead add a specific version number.

```
require.config({
        urlArgs: "ver=1.1.1"
    });
```

Comment: From their docs: `During development it can be useful to use this, however be sure to remove it before deploying your code.`

Comment: @Ian Thx, I'll just replace JS time to a version number or something.

Comment: @Henry Note that this will never allow the JS files to be cached